# Docker: Unhandled Promise rejection when trying to access mongoDB using docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

So I was trying to deploy my very basic Node.js application using docker on a remote linux server(digital ocean droplet) following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/containerizing-a-node-js-application-for-development-with-docker-compose). I'm pretty new to deployment related stuff so i'm surely doing some basic error. Please bear with me for the long post.

The code for project and docker, docker-compose config files that I was using was:

**.env**

```
MONGO_USERNAME=sammy
MONGO_PASSWORD=password
MONGO_DB=sharkinfo
PORT=8080
MONGO_PORT=27017
MONGO_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "src/index.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
      - MONGO_HOSTNAME=myDB
      - MONGO_PORT=$MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_DB=$MONGO_DB
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    networks:
      - app-network
  myDB:
    image: mongo:4.1.8-xenial
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=$MONGO_USERNAME
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGO_PASSWORD
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - app-network
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

**mongoose.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const {
  MONGO_USERNAME,
  MONGO_PASSWORD,
  MONGO_HOSTNAME,
  MONGO_PORT,
  MONGO_DB
} = process.env;

const url = `mongodb://${MONGO_USERNAME}:${MONGO_PASSWORD}@${MONGO_HOSTNAME}:${MONGO_PORT}/${MONGO_DB}?authSource=admin`;

mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
});
```

Then I created and ran a docker image using the commands (in-order) - `docker-compose build` `docker-compose up -d`.
Both the node and mongoDB server show up in list of running docker processes. However when i do `docker logs node-application`, i get an error:

```
Server is up on port 8080
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mydb:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I've tried various tweaks to my code with no success and it continues to give the same error. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Have you already checked if your local MongoDB instance running locally on port 27017 or running on some other port and you can connect to MongoDB with the provided credentials?

Comment: Try to print the connection url and see all the information is accurate from environment variables

Comment: @RajeshDwivedi Using `docker ps` it shows that mongoDB is running on port `27017`. However i'm not sure how to connect to mongoDB using credentials on a remote linux server. Can you explain?

Comment: Use docker ps to get the name of the existing container.
Use the command docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash to get a bash shell in the container.
Once you are in the shell you can connect to mongo using mongoclient
Here is a nice blog for the reference http://www.ifdattic.com/how-to-mongodb-nodejs-docker/